# Removing object required errors

Tags: vba, excel

I am performing a delete function and I tried removing the "object required" whenever there is no or invalid user input.

However when I do so, it does not perform the delete action.

I need help to correct my mistake!

```
Sub deletetry2()

    Dim R As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", , , , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        R.delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You variables (`R` and `rng`) are inconsistent, you should be using
`If TypeName(R) <> "Range" Then`

That said, suggest you try checking for a valid range as below:

```
    Dim R As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set R = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", , , , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If R Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        R.Delete
    End If
```